# MySQL double quotes in WHERE

Tags: mysql, 64-bit, quotes

OK, first allow me to mention that this is not my "first query" or anything, I have been working with PHP and MySQL for years.

The problem I encountered recently is really really odd.

```
SELECT colNameA FROM myTable WHERE colNameB LIKE "G\_%";
```

The point of this query is to fetch all rows from the table which have a prefix of G_.

The query works perfectly on Windows and Linux boxes, running MySQL 5.5 on 64bit (executed directly in MySQL cli). When it is executed on a 32bit box (tested on Linux and Windows) however - it renders an because it considers G_% as column name, which is obviously not the case.

I spent hours researching this and for the life of me - I cannot get an explanation (or a reference to certain MySQL var) why on 32bit MySQL versions the double quotes play the role of a "grave accent" symbol ( ` ), while on 64bit versions they play the role of quotes (which they are supposed to).

I know I can just go ahead and replace the double quotes with single quotes, but that is not really a solution for me in this case. I am working with a platform built with a great deal of queries and I cannot spend a week or so to just convert quotes.

I don't think it matters but for tests I used the following operating systems:

- CentOS 6.6 32bit
- CentOS 6.6 64bit
- Windows 7 32bit
- Windows 7 64bit

The MySQL versions used for testing are 5.5.42, 5.5.41, 5.5.24

Comment: Forgot to mention that I did checked the "sql_mode" on all MySQL versions and "ANSI_QUOTES" is not present there

Comment: `' ` (single quote) is the sql standard so it's odd enough that your query runs at all (given that ansi mode is not enabled, it probably isn't). in the specific case given, you can always resort to `substr(colnameB, 1, 2) = 'G_'` and choose the quotes as they fit (though  substring-ing may prevent the use of an index on the respective column).

Comment: I cannot agree @collapsar

You can clearly see in the official docs that single quotes are used as literals and unless ANSI_QUOTES is enabled - so as double quotes. You can refer to:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-literals.html

Comment: I've been referring to the ANSI standard, not the mysql docs.

Comment: well, I think you just answered it.  sql_mode (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi_quotes) is the key and not the 32/64bit. did you try to check whether it differs for your configurations (`SELECT @@sql_mode;`)?

Comment: As mentioned earlier, I did check the "sql_mode" on all MySQL versions and "ANSI_QUOTES" is not present there. As a matter of fact, the "sql_mode" on all platform is the same - '' I know the behavior does seem like ANSI_QUOTES is enabled but its not, at least it is not being shown as enabled.

Comment: and did you check it with the same session where you send the query with the double-quote? //it might be session specific, a simple set can overwrite it

Comment: the [lexer of mysql](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~mysql/mysql-server/5.7/view/head:/sql/sql_lex.cc#L1738) is pretty clear in that. if sql_mode has ansi_quotes, the token is treated as a variable, otherwise a string (MY_LEX_STRING_OR_DELIMITER is [defined as](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~mysql/mysql-server/5.7/view/head:/mysys/charset.c#L97) the " character).

Comment: You are correct @lp_, the charset.c file does indeed state that, even for ver 5.5, with which I am testing. I set "SELECT @@sql_mode" to be executed before each PHP->mysql query, and I can confirm that sql_mode is empty always. Next I modified the PHP library to actually initiate a new connection for every query and voila - ANSI_QUOTES is now listed (although never set!). So it seems that even if sql_mode is empty as a GLOBAL and SESSION vars, on new connections sql_mode gets set to ANSI_QUOTES. I tested on both 32 and 64bit (identical my.cnf and version) [new installs] and only 32 does this.

Comment: so I guess the question is really about where/when/what turns ansi_quotes on (and not why mysql handles double-quote as a variable). probably it's the connector or sg and not the server. seems to be some nice debugging  ;)